# Akka failure when running integration tests in maven

Tags: java, akka, integration-testing, elastic-mq

I've written some integration tests for a project which, when I run the service in intellij and then run the integration tests works fine, but when I run man clean verify, if causes the following error at the point that I attempt to create the SQSRestServer:

```
NodeAddress serverAddress = new NodeAddress("http", "localhost", configuration.getElasticMQPort(), "");
server = SQSRestServerBuilder
            .withPort(configuration.getElasticMQPort())
            .withServerAddress(serverAddress)
            .start();
```

The error that I get when running in maven is as follows:

> [ERROR] Exception in thread "main"
>
> [ERROR] java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 152
>
> [ERROR] Exception Details:
>
> [ERROR]   Location:
>
> [ERROR]     akka/dispatch/Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages()V @152: getstatic
>
> [ERROR]   Reason:
>
> [ERROR]     Type top (current frame, locals[9]) is not assignable to 'akka/dispatch/sysmsg/SystemMessage' (stack map, locals[9])
>
> [ERROR]   Current Frame:
>
> [ERROR]     bci: @131
>
> [ERROR]     flags: { }
>   [ERROR]     locals: { 'akka/dispatch/Mailbox', 'java/lang/InterruptedException', 'akka/dispatch/sysmsg/SystemMessage', top, 'akka/dispatch/Mailbox', 'java/lang/Throwable', 'java/lang/Throwable' }
>
> [ERROR]     stack: { integer }
>
> [ERROR]   Stackmap Frame:
>
> [ERROR]     bci: @152
>
> [ERROR]     flags: { }
>
> [ERROR]     locals: { 'akka/dispatch/Mailbox', 'java/lang/InterruptedException', 'akka/dispatch/sysmsg/SystemMessage', top, 'akka/dispatch/Mailbox', 'java/lang/Throwable', 'java/lang/Throwable', top, top, 'akka/dispatch/sysmsg/SystemMessage' }
>
> [ERROR]     stack: { }
>
> [ERROR]   Bytecode:
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000000: 014c 2ab2 0132 b601 35b6 0139 4db2 013e
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000010: 2cb6 0142 9900 522a b600 c69a 004b 2c4e
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000020: b201 3e2c b601 454d 2db9 0148 0100 2ab6
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000030: 0052 2db6 014b b801 0999 000e bb00 e759
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000040: 1301 4db7 010f 4cb2 013e 2cb6 0150 99ff
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000050: bf2a b600 c69a ffb8 2ab2 0132 b601 35b6
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000060: 0139 4da7 ffaa 2ab6 0052 b600 56b6 0154
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000070: b601 5a3a 04a7 0091 3a05 1905 3a06 1906
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000080: c100 e799 0015 1906 c000 e73a 0719 074c
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000090: b200 f63a 08a7 0071 b201 5f19 06b6 0163
>
> [ERROR]     0x00000a0: 3a0a 190a b601 6899 0006 1905 bf19 0ab6
>
> [ERROR]     0x00000b0: 016c c000 df3a 0b2a b600 52b6 0170 b601
>
> [ERROR]     0x00000c0: 76bb 000f 5919 0b2a b600 52b6 017a b601
>
> [ERROR]     0x00000d0: 80b6 0186 2ab6 018a bb01 8c59 b701 8e13
>
> [ERROR]     0x00000e0: 0190 b601 9419 09b6 0194 1301 96b6 0194
>
> [ERROR]     0x00000f0: 190b b601 99b6 0194 b601 9ab7 019d b601
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000100: a3b2 00f6 3a08 b201 3e2c b601 4299 0026
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000110: 2c3a 09b2 013e 2cb6 0145 4d19 09b9 0148
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000120: 0100 1904 2ab6 0052 b601 7a19 09b6 01a7
>
> [ERROR]     0x0000130: a7ff d62b c600 09b8 0109 572b bfb1
>
> [ERROR]   Exception Handler Table:
>
> [ERROR]     bci [290, 307] => handler: 120
>
> [ERROR]   Stackmap Tab
>
> [ERROR] le:
>
> [ERROR]     append_frame(@13,Object[#231],Object[#177])
>
> [ERROR]     append_frame(@71,Object[#177])
>
> [ERROR]     chop_frame(@102,1)
>
> [ERROR]     full_frame(@120,{Object[#2],Object[#231],Object[#177],Top,Object[#2],Object[#177]},{Object[#223]})
>
> [ERROR]     full_frame(@152,{Object[#2],Object[#231],Object[#177],Top,Object[#2],Object[#223],Object[#223],Top,Top,Object[#177]},{})
>
> [ERROR]     append_frame(@173,Object[#357])
>
> [ERROR]     full_frame(@262,{Object[#2],Object[#231],Object[#177],Top,Object[#2]},{})
>
> [ERROR]     same_frame(@307)
>
> [ERROR]     same_frame(@317)
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR]         at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.(Mailboxes.scala:33)
>
> [ERROR]         at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.
>
> (ActorSystem.scala:620)
>
> [ERROR]         at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
>
> [ERROR]         at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
>
> [ERROR]         at org.elasticmq.rest.sqs.TheSQSRestServerBuilder$$anonfun$getOrCreateActorSystem$2.apply(SQSRestServerBuilder.scala:178)
>
> [ERROR]         at org.elasticmq.rest.sqs.TheSQSRestServerBuilder$$anonfun$getOrCreateActorSystem$2.apply(SQSRestServerBuilder.scala:177)
>
> [ERROR]         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>
> [ERROR]         at org.elasticmq.rest.sqs.TheSQSRestServerBuilder.getOrCreateActorSystem(SQSRestServerBuilder.scala:177)
>
> [ERROR]         at org.elasticmq.rest.sqs.TheSQSRestServerBuilder.start(SQSRestServerBuilder.scala:88)
>
> [ERROR]       [redacted, company specific]

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I have a similar issue with Spark Streaming using RabbitMQ (spark-rabbitmq lib). Can you please suggest if you have resolved it and how...thanks

Comment: I've not resolved it yet, unfortunately.